# How to give multiple conditions in if statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach, multiple-conditions

I have written a VBA code to auto hide rows when the three column " D" , "E" and "F" simultaneously show zero value. If any one of them is having non-zero value it should not hide the rows. Moreover, I also want to add "#N/A" also, like if #NA is there just like Zero it should hide the row.

But it seems there is some problem with the code.

```
Sub HideRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
 
For Each x In Range("D2:D2000")
Next
For Each y In Range("E2:E2000")
Next
For Each Z In Range("F2:F2000")
Next
If x.Value = 0 And y.Value = 0 And Z.Value = 0 Then x.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You do know how to nest loops right?  You've got three loops that do nothing, then an IF statement at the end that checks nothing (well likely checks D2000,E2000,F2000).  All your "Next"s should be after the IF statement at a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

Your syntax is not correct. The loop `For Each ... Next` should encompass the code that you want to repeat . Since your loop does not contain anything inside, it does absolutely nothing. I tried to write an understandable code for you:

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim i as Long 'Counter
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To 2000
        If (.Range("D" & i).Value = 0 Or .Range("D" & i).Text = "#N/A") And _
           (.Range("E" & i).Value = 0 Or .Range("E" & i).Text = "#N/A") And _
           (.Range("F" & i).Value = 0 Or .Range("F" & i).Text = "#N/A") Then
        .Range("D" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End With

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In the example you see that the loop `For ... Next` encompasses some code, therefore the code will be done, as you can see, for 1999 times counting from 2 to 2000.Everything is enclosed in `With ActiveSheet ... End With` statement. The reason is to make the code more readable and not to repeat `ActiveSheet`. If you did not use it, instead of `.Range` you would have to write the full thing (`ActiveSheet.Range`).